# Sign in with apple - authenticate subsequent calls without showing the sign in UI (refreshing authentication token)

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

Whenever I start my app, I want to make sure apple sign in is still valid, but I also want to be able to **prove** it to my server.
After a successful login, I can use `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider.getCredentialState` to figure out if my credentials are still valid for subsequent logins.
This works fine, but there is no way to prove to my server that this process was successfully performed, and anyone that uses my server API could just tell the server not to worry and the server would have no way of telling if it's a real client or not.
The server can also use the refresh token to verify the user is still valid, by issuing a new access token (Apple says to do it no more than once a day, but OK for now), but this doesn't help either as I don't want the secret to be present in the client app, and besides, even if I get a new access token from the client side - the server can't use it for anything for the time being as no API currently exists that does *anything* with the access token.

What I require is a new authentication token, however - when invoking `ASAuthorizationController.performRequests()` with an Apple ID request - the UI shows again, and does not just calls the `ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate` with a new authorization token.
I also tried setting the request operation to `refresh` in the second login attempt:

```
    let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
    request.requestedOperation = .operationRefresh
```

Same result, the UI still shows.
Is there a way to re-authenticate with Apple ID without showing the UI, and get some sort of token which can be used by the server to verify the authenticity of the login?
Please don't suggest of out of scope methods, such as those that involve my own sign in mechanism after initial proof to the server and having the server use the refresh token from that point on - I can come up with those solutions on my own - I'm looking for an apple sign in approach solution.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: @HTron It appears there's no real solution.  Right now I create a token in my server, provide that as a response to the client, and the client uses that token to sign in from that point on.  From time to time I refresh the original apple token, just to make sure it's still there, and when the app receives an event that says the user had signed out - I notify the server to remove the token and sign out.  It's crap, but it is what it is, apple didn't seem to think this one through.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. That is suboptimal indeed. Well, I guess there are not that many options left at this point. I wonder if this approach works conveniently with one user using the same account on multiple devices. I'm just trying to think it through.. Greetings from Kreuzberg

Comment: @HTron Greetings neighbor :-) I'm in In Friedrichshain

Comment: I'm really surprised that more developers are not cranky about this issue. The question asked by the OP seems a central use case, but not well supported by Apple. In my communication with Apple DTS, they seem to avoid this question.

Comment: @ChrisPrince I believe that in the future we could use the auth token to query information from apple (like its done with Facebook), and as a by product- this issue will be resolved.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb Perhaps coming with iOS 14? One possibly good thing is that they haven't closed my DTS ticket on this matter.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/verifying_a_user):

> After verifying the identity token, your app is responsible for
>   managing the user session. **You may tie the session’s lifetime to
>   successful getCredentialState(forUserID:completion:) calls on Apple
>   devices**. This is a local, inexpensive, nonnetwork call and is enabled
>   by the Apple ID system that keeps the Apple ID state on a device in
>   sync with Apple servers.
>
> **User interaction is required any time a new identity token is requested.** User sessions are long-lived on device, so calling for a
>   new identity token on every launch, or more frequently than once a
>   day, **can result in your request failing due to throttling**.
>
> If the user’s Apple ID changes in the system, calls to
>   getCredentialState(forUserID:completion:) indicate that the user
>   changed. **Assume that a different user has signed in and log out the
>   app’s currently known user.**
>
> For apps running on other systems, use the periodic successful
>   verification of the refresh token to determine the lifetime of the
>   user session.

So this basically means you should be checking the userIdentifier when getting result from getCredentialState and make sure it is the same value as the current user has.
And you can't avoid the user interaction you mention in the question, if you want to re-authenticate in the app.

First of all, you have to take the userIdentifier and the authorizationCode from the app sign in and send it to your server. Also make a long session id and send that to your server too:

```
if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {

        let userIdentifier = appleIDCredential.user
        print("userIdentifier: \(userIdentifier)")

        let authorizationCode = String(data: appleIDCredential.authorizationCode!, encoding: .utf8)!
        print("authorizationCode: \(authorizationCode)")  

        let sessionID = veryLongToken

        //send authorizationCode, userIdentifier and sessionId to server
    }
```

On your server you obtain the identityToken when calling: appleid.apple.com/token/auth

with:

```
#create token
import jwt  # pip install pyjwt
claims = {
    'iss': teamID,
    'iat': timeNow,
    'exp': time3Months,
    'aud': 'https://appleid.apple.com',
    'sub': app_id,
}
client_secret = jwt.encode(claims, private_key_from_developer_portal, algorithm='ES256', headers={'kid': kid})


data = {
    'client_id': app_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'grant_type': grant_type,
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
    'code': authorizationCode,
}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

response = requests.request(
    method='POST',
    url='https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token',
    data=data,
    headers=headers,
)
#response will include refresh_token, access_token and id_token
```

You can now retrieve the user email and the userIdentifier from the id_token:

```
result = jwt.decode(id_token, verify=False)
print("jwtResult: " + result)

userIdentifier = result["sub"]
email = result["email"]
```

Now you know from apple what user it is. According to
[validate token documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/generate_and_validate_tokens) you first use authorization_code in grant_type to get the refresh_token and after that use refresh_token as grant_type

This is the only way to verify the user is still authenticated on the server.

So store the sessionId along with some information about the apple sign in (refresh token...) on your server.

You can make the app send the sessionId to the server when the app needs data from the server and before handing over some information to the app, do the refresh token validation on the server. If the authentication is not valid, then the app should delete the sessionId and log out.

This is the only way you are going to be able to validate on your server if the authentication is valid.

By reading the documentation this seems to be the recommended way and what you are trying to do is going to cause problems and apple doesn't want you to authenticate the user in the app all the time.

You should also check out this example project from apple for sign in with apple.

[juice example project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple)

Comment: Thanks! while it doesn't really answer my question (provide proof to the server on subsequent requests) - it basically covers what I've already gathered: there's no way to do that, and once authenticated, I need to use my own authentication scheme from that point (a long running session is just one example), and of course, run client side tests to revoke the sign in and periodic server token refresh.